# How do I create a distributable Java template for Netbeans 7.1?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm trying to create a distributable module for Netbeans 7.1 which will contain a license template and some java templates. I'm following the tutorial at [Netbean's support](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html) but they only talk about how to create an HTML template. If I create a java file to use as a template, the builder tries to compile the template and fails.

My project looks like this:

```
Netbeans Code Template Module
  + org.myorg.nbcodetemplates
    - Bundle.properties
    + org.myorg.nbcodetemplates.javaclass
      - JavaClass.java
      - JavaClassDescription.html
      - package-info.java
    + org.myorg.nbcodetemplates.license
      - LicenseDescription.html
      - license-myorg.txt
      - package-info.java
```

How do I get the builder to skip the Java template - or is there something else I should have done here? It seems to be happy if I leave the JavaClass.java named JavaClass.html and build the module that way, but it shows up as an HTML file when I try to add it to a project through the New File wizard.

Comment: I wish I could help. You might try asking this question in the NetBeans Platform users forum at http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change name of your file from

JavaClass.java

to

JavaClass.java.template

after that .template will be removed automatically